# Qwidget, how to highlight the widget under the cursor

Tags: c++, qt

I have created some QLabel type of widgets in QT, and added that to a QToolbar. I want to highlight the particular widget which is under the cursor. I am unable to understand how do I do that. Can somebody please help ? I need this information on QT 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You have several possibilities.
First, as you subclass QLabel, you can handle [mouse events](http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.5/widgets-scribble.html) directly in your class.
Make sure to use QWidget::setMouseTracking() to enable this.
In such scenario you can do whatever you want with your control but you will have to
override paint routine so that your class can draw itself in some specific way.

Unfortunately QLabel does not support "hover" style sheet state so that you cannot
do it easily with styles sheets. However, if you consider subclassing from QPushButton you can have this wonderful feature
so that with the help of CSS you get nice highliting effect. 
For more info on style sheets in QT look [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton).

If subclassing QPushButton is fine for you, then look [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton). 
Just make sure you also use hover state like in this simple example:

```
QPushButton:hover {
     background-color: black;
 }
QPushButton:hover {
     background-color: white;
 }
```

Example for the mouse events handling can be found [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.5/widgets-scribble.html)

Comment: Hi,
     Thanks for your answer. Could you please point me to specific example where mouse events are handled for QLabel. Also I tried using QPushButton, but it shows some frames and all, which I dont want, thats why I used QLabel. But please point me to some example code of QPushButton as well.
thanks.

Comment: You could not do the painting yourself, but just change the background color of the palette on mouse enter/mouse leave events.  That should be sufficient.